# Capturing **vars() pattern in string formatting

Tags: python, scope, string-formatting

I frequently find myself using the following pattern for string formatting.

```
a = 3
b = 'foo'
c = dict(mykey='myval')

#prints a is 3, b is foo, mykey is myval
print('a is {a}, b is {b}, mykey is {c[mykey]}'.format(**vars()))
```

That is, I often have the values I need to print in the local namespace, represented by a call to vars(). As I look over my code, however, it seems awfully unpythonic to be constantly repeating the `.format(**vars())` pattern.

I'd like to create a function that will capture this pattern. It would be something like the following.

```
# doesn't work
def lfmt(s):
    """
    lfmt (local format) will format the string using variables
    in the caller's local namespace.
    """
    return s.format(**vars())
```

Except that by the time I'm in the `lfmt` namespace, vars() is no longer what I want.

How can I write lfmt so that it executes vars() in the caller's namespace such that the following code would work as the example above?

```
print(lfmt('a is {a}, b is {b}, mykey is {c[mykey]}'))
```

Comment: Your request would seem to go against the Python spirit of "Explicit is better than implicit."  I no longer quite have the Python chops I once did, but I can't think of any way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: In order for `lfmt` to work when called from different namespaces, you'll need the `inspect` module. Note, as [the documentation warns](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe), the `inspect` module may not be suitable for production code since it may not work with all implementations of Python

```
import inspect
def lfmt(s):
    caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    return s.format(**caller.f_locals)

a = 3
b = 'foo'
c = dict(mykey='myval')

print(lfmt('a is {a}, b is {b}, mykey is {c[mykey]}'))
# a is 3, b is foo, mykey is myval
```

Comment: Thanks. That works when the caller is in the global namespace, but not when the caller is in some other scope.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, you are right. I've edited my answer to make lfmt work across namespaces.

Comment: Excellent. That's almost it. Change f_globals to f_locals and it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inspect the variables from the calling frames.

This will get you started:

```
import inspect
import pprint

def lfmt(s):
    for frame in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe()):
        f = frame[0]
        print pprint.pformat(f.f_locals)
    return '???'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = 30
    lfmt('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
import sys

def lfmt(s):
    """
    lfmt (local format) will format the string using variables
    in the caller's local namespace.
    """

    if hasattr(sys, "tracebacklimit") and sys.tracebacklimit == 0:
        raise Exception, "failfailfail"

    try:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        f = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back

    return s.format(**f.f_locals)

a = 5
somestring = "text"
print lfmt("{a} {somestring}")
```

The fact that it works doesn't mean you should use it. This is what developers call "major hack", usually shipped with a comment "XXX fix me XXX".

Comment: This is good. And I think there's a cleaner solution that involves the inspect module that lost-theory pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it so bad to type `,vars` each time you call the function?

```
def lfmt(s,v):
    """
    lfmt (local format) will format the string using variables
    from the dict returned by calling v()"""
    return s.format(**v())

print(lfmt('a is {a}, b is {b}, mykey is {c[mykey]}',vars))
```

Comment: It's not _so_ bad, but if I'm going to go through the trouble of creating a function, I'm not going to ask the caller to pass the same thing every time, especially if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sys` instead of `inspect`, but I don't know if it has the same problem with different implementations as `inspect` has.

```
import sys

def lfmt(s):
    caller = sys._getframe(1)
    return s.format(**caller.f_locals)
```

This is as far as I got: [Python string interpolation implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504732/python-string-interpolation-implementation)