# Of what use is the vars() function?

Tags: python

I have came across the function `vars()` in python i know it returns `__dict__` attribute of the object passed to the function But can you give me a real world usage example  like where we can use it in real project

Comment: ... whenever you want access to `__dict__`, no?

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice, but sometimes it is useful when you don't want to pass all the variables when formatting string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201867/capturing-vars-pattern-in-string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Let me take an example:
sometimes you may need check a class object's attribute is None or others, you can use the vars()

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.c = None

    def init_abc(self, init_dict):
        """init class param"""
        self.a = init_dict.get('a')
        self.b = init_dict.get('b')
        self.c = init_dict.get('c')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'a=%s,b=%s, c=%s' % (self.a, self.b, self.c)

test = Test()
init_abc_dict = {'a':1, 'c':2}
test.init_abc(init_abc_dict)
print 'Test:%s' % test
if None in vars(test).values():
    print 'some attr is None'
```